# Copy Image with filters from one canvas and paste to other

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs, camanjs

I'm using Fabric library to draw different objects on canvas and for some image i need to provide effects and filter, so i'm using Caman library. 
I'm providing the effects and filter functionality in popup where i added another canvas and gets the URL of selected image, but after applying effects on image through Caman librray, i need to put back that image to main canvas. But problem is, i need to put back image with same size and without resolution loss.
Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You have following method to export canvas :

`toObject
toSVG 
toJSON 
toDatalessJSON 
toDataURL('png')`

you can use any one method from above you can export canvas which is there in that popup and can import to your main canvas by following methods :

`loadFromJSON 
loadFromDatalessJSON 
loadSVGFromString 
loadSVGFromURL`